# Javascript: Date: How to get year 1

Tags: javascript, date

`new Date(1,0,1)` will return year *19*01. The reason is Javascript's mapping of years  0~99 to 1900~1999.

```js
console.log(new Date(1,0,1));
```

###### Question

Is there a way to circumvent the mapping and get the actual *year 1* ?

###### Background:

I'm updating a `Date` variable in a React project, while the user types in values in a datetime-local field (Because it's react, onChange will be triggered on every keystroke). When the user starts typing this will result in something like *year 1*, which should not be mapped to 1901 at that time.

Comment: You mean, as soon as the user starts typing, it's registering as 1901? if that's the case, why don't you ignore first few character or so in your onChange?

Comment: The `change` event won’t actually be triggered as the user is typing, unless you’re using an `<input type="datetime-local">`. But its `valueAsDate` property handles year 1 correctly.

Comment: when i tried this `console.log(new Date(0,0,-693300))`, i got `Mon Oct 22 0001 00:00:00 GMT+0642 (Indochina Time)`

Comment: Create a *date*, then use *setFullYear*: `let d = new Date(); d.setFullYear(1,0,1);`. You might want to zero the time too: `d.setHours(0,0,0,0)`.

Comment: I don't know for sure what actual value `datetime-local` generates, or whether it's standard across browsers, but this is a use case where parsing date from text can actually make sense, given that the API for individual components has such quirk.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all commenters!

Here's my solution and (for documenting purposes) an answer to the comments.

#### My Solution

I went with `setFullYear(year)`. ([RobG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257182/robg)'s comment)

###### Example:

```
function createDate(y,m,d,h=0,m=0,s=0){
  const ret = new Date(y,m,d,h,m,s); 
  ret.setFullYear(y); // ← setFullYear does not have a mapping
  return ret;
}
```

#### Other solutions

###### `datetime-local`: `valueAsDate` / `onChange` behavior

[Sebastian Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4642212/sebastian-simon) suggested working on `<input type="datetime-local">`

> The change event won’t actually be triggered as the user is typing

Is a solution. 
Didn't work in my use case, because React's `onChange` is fired on every keystroke (updated question after the comment)

> [datetime-local's] `valueAsDate` property handles year 1 correctly.

Firefox specific behavior. 
`valueAsDate` does not exist in Chrome.

#### new Date(0,0,-693300)

[Layhout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17308201/layhout) commented on the effect of `new Date(0,0,-693300)`. This is essentially the same you get with `setFullYear(1)`. 
This works, because Date will calculate `1900 - 693300 days`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Indeed. I didn't know that (= I didn't know that React, which I'm using, changes the behavior to that extend). I updated my question and answer. Thank you for pursuing this!